# Proving a quadratic function is bijective in given range

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, quadratics

Prove that $f: [0,\infty[ \to [-5,\infty[$ defined as $f(x) = 4x^2+4x-5$ is bijective. I can prove it graphically but not algebraically.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Can you calculate $f^{-1}$?

Comment: Do you know calculus?  That would make it easy to show that $f$ is strictly increasing

Comment: @J.W.Tanner even without calculus, that's not too hard to prove. I think your point about "strictly increasing" is the key one for this question, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:
\begin{equation}
f(x_1)=f(x_2) \implies 4x^2_1+4x_1-5=4x^2_2+4x_2-5 \implies x_1^2-x_2^2+x_1-x_2=0 \implies\\
(x_1-x_2)(x_1+x_2)+(x_1-x_2)=0 \implies (x_1-x_2)(x_1+x_2+1)=0
\end{equation}
Since $x_1,x_2 \geq 0$, it means $x_1+x_2+1 > 0$. This implies that $x_1-x_2=0 \implies x_1=x_2$, meaning the function is injective.

---

Surjection:
\begin{equation}
f(x)=y \implies 4x^2+4x-5=y
\end{equation}
Ordinary quadratic equation. Solve it and prove that x is real and positive for $y\geq -5$ (the part under the root has to be non-negative). ***Note:*** I have not done the calculation myself.

Answer (score 0):

It is surjective: given some $y \in [-5,\infty)$, we can solve the equation $f(x) = y$ by $$
4x^2 + 4x-5 = y \implies x = \frac{\pm\sqrt{y+6}-1}{2}.
$$ Because $y$ is bigger than $-5$, this is well-defined so indeed $f$ is surjective. Furthermore, the negative branch of the square root, i.e. the solution $x=\frac{-\sqrt{y+6}-1}{2}$ will always be negative. So, in the given domain $[0,\infty)$, the solution for $x$ is unique, proving that $f$ is injective.